# java bufferedreader in combination with ready(), read() does not return -1

Tags: java

I have the following which sleeps after reading everything:

```
       while (true){
            if(reader.ready()){
                int intVal = reader.read();
                log.info("char: "+intVal);
                if(intVal == -1){
                    break;
                }
                char character = (char) intVal;
                line.append(character);
            }else{
                try {
                    log.info("sleeping");
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            long elapsedSeconds = watch.getTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if(elapsedSeconds > maxTimeToExecuteCommand){
                log.error("max read time elapsed.");
                break;
            }
        }
```

output is like:

```
char: 65
char: 66
char: 67
sleeping
sleeping
sleeping
....
....
goes on till elapsedSeconds is reached
```

the problem being intVal never gets a -1 which is weird.

whereas doing

```
        List<String> fullConsoleOutput = reader.lines()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

works perfectly.

I do know about setting a timeout on a socket instead of doing this whole loop thing, but opening and closing a socket multiple times is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public int read()
>            throws IOException
>
> Reads a single character. This method will block until a character is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.

So having read the last char, *before* seeing the end-of-file, -1, it blocks on reading, `ready()` giving false, till -1 would have been read.
Another term in I/O code would be `available()` what would have been a better term for this behaviour.

You might try to read part of an char array (length 1), maybe getting 0 read at the end.

*P.S.*

*My explanation is not realy that convincing.*